# Firebase Firestore: get document ID after adding data offline

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, offline

I add data to Firestore like this:

```
db
    .collection('foo')
    .add({foo: 'bar'})
    .then(docRef => {
      console.log('Added Foo: ', docRef.id)
      // do some stuff here with the newly created foo and it's id.
    })
    .catch(console.error)
```

After the document creation, I would like to work with the new doc or specially it's ID. The document is stored in the local database with a valid ID.

But how do I get the ID after the document creation? The promise will not be resolved until the data has synced with the server.

Comment: I don't see the problem here. You want to do something with the id, so do it at the part that says `// do some stuff here with the newly created foo and it's id.`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe this part will never be executed as long as you run offline

Comment: Dennis did you found a good solution to this problem, or a workarround, that be easy/optimal to implement on an hybrid app that requires offline, and that will need those ids to save child data?

Comment: @moplin yes, see my own answer below

Answer (score 12):

You can get Id even before you are saving locally. You just use this way to write data.

```
      // Add a new document with a generated id.
     var newCityRef = db.collection("cities").doc();
      var id = newCityRef.key;
      // later...
       newCityRef.set(data);
```

For the web, offline persistence is disabled by default. To enable persistence, call the enablePersistence method

```
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()
  .then(function() {
      // Initialize Cloud Firestore through firebase
      var db = firebase.firestore();
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
      if (err.code == 'failed-precondition') {
          // Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled
          // in one tab at a a time.
          // ...
      } else if (err.code == 'unimplemented') {
          // The current browser does not support all of the
          // features required to enable persistence
          // ...
      }
```

To check whether you're receiving data from the server or the cache, use the fromCache property on the SnapshotMetadata in your snapshot event. IffromCache is true, the data came from the cache and might be stale or incomplete. If fromCache is false, the data is complete and current with the latest updates on the server.

By default, no event is raised if only the SnapshotMetadata changed. If you rely on the fromCache values, specify the includeMetadataChanges listen option when you attach your listen handler.

```
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
  .onSnapshot({ includeQueryMetadataChanges: true }, function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.docChanges.forEach(function(change) {
          if (change.type === "added") {
              console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
          }

          var source = snapshot.metadata.fromCache ? "local cache" : "server";
          console.log("Data came from " + source);
      });
  });
```

So if you add new data and you have offline enabled your data will be added to cache and can be listened by the listeners.

});

Comment: okay. That gives me the ID of the object. But this is of no use for me until the object exists in the local database and this is done async. I still don't see any other way then using the workaround below.

Comment: I have stated the offline capabilities in my answer now. So whenever you add new data it gets added to cache and you can use it anywhere , when  you connect back to internet it ll be written to server.

Comment: I have offline persistence enabled. It was no question on how to enable it. I do get the difference between cache and server, but it does not matter in that context. My question is: "is there a better solution, than my workaround below, which I find suboptimal for the stated reasons, to get the object and it's ID after it's creation?". I don't know how else to put it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this workaround that does the job for me.

```
db
    .collection('foo')
    .where('fooCreator', '==', currentUserId)
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.docChanges.forEach(change => {
        if (change.type === 'added' && change.doc._document.hasLocalMutations) {
          const fooId = change.doc.id
          const foo = change.doc.data()
          // do something with foo and fooId
        }
      })
    })
```

It works, but I don't really like it because of:

1. I need to subscribe to **all** changes
2. I used `change.doc._document.hasLocalMutations` to check if it is a newly created item